# Tool to convert large Mozilla LZ4 files to plain text?

Tags: command-line, firefox, file-compression, data-extraction

*TL;DR*: I am seeking for software to turn Mozilla's headacheful LZ4 garbage into usable plain text.

There is already a [scrounger for Mozilla LZ4,](https://www.jeffersonscher.com/res/scrounger.html) which even is supposed to work offline when saving the page, but that does not work properly.

Is there any simple command line interface powered program to convert huge LZ4 data to plain text?

Disclosure: I am not a fan of LZ4.

> I actually despise Lz4.

Comment: For which operating system(s)?  What price range, or gratis?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Linux Terminal (preferrably cross-platform), gratis. But existing archival programs can not make any sense of this LZ4, even after installing LZ4 packages.

Comment: Thank you for the details.  Please update your question and tags to reflect them.  Thanks!